# Everytime I'm going to use external sources I get: collect2. exe: error ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

For example this code, I create a new project in codeblocks, add these files, enable the header file and when trying to run it i get:

-------------- Build: Debug in date (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -I..\date -c
>   "C:\Users\kairenne\Documents\programming\chapter
>   8\monster_generation\date\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\date.exe obj\Debug\Date.o Date.h.gch
>   obj\Debug\main.o    Date.h.gch: file not recognized: File format not
>   recognized collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Process
>   terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) 1 error(s), 0
>   warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))

Date.h

```
#define DATE_H

class Date
{
private:
    int m_year;
    int m_month;
    int m_day;

public:
    Date(int year, int month, int day);

    void SetDate(int year, int month, int day);

    int getYear() { return m_year; }
    int getMonth() { return m_month; }
    int getDay()  { return m_day; }
};

#endif
```

Date.cpp

```
// Date constructor
Date::Date(int year, int month, int day)
{
    SetDate(year, month, day);
}

// Date member function
void Date::SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    m_month = month;
    m_day = day;
    m_year = year;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date test(2000, 05, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, the `#ifndef` is missing and I would rather have a constructor like `Date::Date(int year, int month, int day): m_year(year), m_month(month), m_day(day){}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never compile or link header file. 
So remove that `Data.h.gch` from your linker's command and you'll be fine.

If it's done automatically for you in your IDE, disable "precompiled header" option.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I don't know where its that option on codeblocks